# Trigger click on a element by clicking another element

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
<div class="news">
 <div class="news-item"></div>
 <div class="news-item"></div>
 <div class="news-item"></div>
</div>

<div class="news-info">
 <div class="info-item"></div>
 <div class="info-item"></div>
 <div class="info-item"></div>
</div>
```

Hi! I have a html code just like the above. How can I trigger click event (using jQuery) on each 'info-item' element from 'news-info' div by clicking each element from the above 'news' div? I mean: when I click the first news-item to trigger click event on the first info-item and the same for the second and the third. I tried something like that:

```
$( ".news" ).each(function() {

        $(this).find( "news-item" ).on('click', function() {

            $('.news-info').find('.info-item').trigger('click');

        });

    });
```

Comment: If I understant well, if you click on the FIRST "news-item" you want to trigger the FIRST "info-item", the SECOND "news-item" the SECOND "info-item", etc.?

Comment: yes, just like that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `eq()` that will allow you to select element based on his index and use `index()` to get the index of an element. With both functions, you can easily map the **i-th** element in the first container with the **i-th** element of the second one.

```js
$(".news .news-item").click(function() {
  $(".news-info").find(".info-item").eq($(this).index()).trigger('click');
});


/* To test the click event */
$(".info-item").click(function() {
  $(this).css('color', 'red');
})
```

```css
div {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="news">
  <div class="news-item">a</div>
  <div class="news-item">b</div>
  <div class="news-item">c</div>
</div>

<div class="news-info">
  <div class="info-item">1</div>
  <div class="info-item">2</div>
  <div class="info-item">3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$( ".news" ).each(function() {

    $(this).find( "news-item" ).on('click', function() {

        $('.news-info').find('.info-item').click();

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If the corresponding divs sequentially match you can grab the index of the clicked `.news-item` via `index()` and find the other through `eq()`. From there you can trigger the click. I added a second click handler just as an example.

```js
$('.news .news-item').on('click', function() {
  var currentIndex = $(this).index();

  $('.news-info .info-item').eq(currentIndex).trigger('click');
});

$('.news-info .info-item').on('click', function() {
  console.log("I'm " + this.textContent + " and I've been clicked or clicked through a trigger!")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="news">
  <div class="news-item">News Item 1</div>
  <div class="news-item">News Item 2</div>
  <div class="news-item">News Item 3</div>
</div>

<div class="news-info">
  <div class="info-item">Info Item 1</div>
  <div class="info-item">Info Item 2</div>
  <div class="info-item">Info Item 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this

```
$(".news div:first").click(function() {
$( ".news-info div:first" ).trigger( "click" ); 
});
```

try it online https://jsfiddle.net/2w27nLos/